# Yii's URL manager rules reading from a MySQL table

Tags: php, url-rewriting, url-routing, yii

Is it possible to have this kind of array:

```
 'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

            '/admin' => '/admin/home',
            '/admin/<controller:\w+>' => '/admin/<controller>',
            '/admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '/admin/<controller>/<action>',
            '/admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '/admin/<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Be read from a database table?

**Why:** I'm making a CMS in which I want to define a custom ***categories, pages and posts*** base so that I don't use a base controller.

Example: My Pages controller is PagesController and I can make a rule in URL manager like this:

```
/pages/some-page-alias
```

I want to be able to change `/pages/`, `/categories/` and `/posts/` to something localized, meaning to be able to change it i.e. on Bosnian:

```
/kategorije/ => /categories/,
/stranice/ => /pages/,
/clanci/ => /posts/,
```

Is there a solution for this, how it can be done?

Btw, I have not tried anything because I have no idea...

Comment: Can you give an example of "define a custom categories, pages and posts base so that I don't use a base controller"?

Comment: Please let me change question's content.

Comment: @Pitchinnate Edited. Please see the question now.

Comment: You don't need to do that via database you can do that in the URL manager I will put an answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'rules' => array(
            'kategorije/<id:\d+>' => 'category/view',
            'kategorije/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'category/<action>',
            'kategorije/<action:\w+>' => 'category/<action>',

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

            '/admin' => '/admin/home',
            '/admin/<controller:\w+>' => '/admin/<controller>',
            '/admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '/admin/<controller>/<action>',
            '/admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '/admin/<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

URLManager prioritizes by what is listed first. So if you put in a custom rule above the standard rules it will run those rules first. Once it finds a rule that applies it breaks out.

Comment: no, you do not understand. I do not want my clients to edit the config.php for that. I need it in a Web form :)

Comment: Will each on be a separate install? Or one system with multiple clients?

Comment: Seperate installations... similar to wordpress!

Comment: Well if it is separate installations you can setup the rules for them in there config file. Or you can take a look here to see if it helps
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/5178-dynamic-url-manager-routes/

Answer (score 0):

As for me, your question is not clear.

If you want to store array in DB you can do it by `serialize`'ing it before.

If you want multiple names pointing to same controller you can use such a rule:

```
array(
     '<_c:(stranica|page)>/<id:\d+>'=>'myController/view',
)
```

In this case if any of urls

```
http://example.com/stranica/123
http://example.com/page/123
```

is requested, it will point to

```
http://example.com/myController/view?_c=stranica&id=123
http://example.com/myController/view?_c=page&id=123
```

accordingly. See [CUrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager) examples in API.